# Explain http://stackauth.com/0.9/help/method?method=users/{id}/associated

Tags: discussion

Any One knows what this does?
 What Id should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `association_id` returned as part of a user object, as in [`/users`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?help).

This returns the user's accounts on any other site they might be on.  Think of it as a window into the user accounts tab.